# How to solve this propability density function?

Tags: probability, functions, random-variables, exponential-function, density-function

I have a function, which I think is a exponential probability function. It is defined as this:

$$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{c}{x^3},  & \text{if $x$ $\geq$ 1} \\[2ex]
0, & \text{else}
\end{cases} $$

Now, the question is: Determine the value of $c$, such that $f(x)$ is indeed a proper density function.
And: Determine $E(X)$ and $P(X>EX)$.

PS: I have tried to solve the question by using properties of the exponential function, but was confused by determining the $c$.

Thank you in advance for explaining the situation for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability mass must be 1, so
$$\int_1^\infty c/x^3 =c/2$$
yields the equation:
$$c/2=1$$
Assuming that the domain for $x$ is all of the real line.